# Is my function to convert image URLs to base64 returning corrupt data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, base64, todataurl

I'm using this script to convert image URLs to base64, but it's generating some funky strings that appear corrupt and I don't know why.

Regardless of if they are corrupt, Airtable is rejecting some of data strings that this function is generating and it's not easy to debug their error which is `error: "INVALID_VALUE_FOR_COLUMN" message: "Field \"LogoBase64\" cannot accept the provided value"`

The only thing Airtable should care about is if it's a primitive string or not.

Example incomeing URL: https://dl.airtable.com/.attachmentThumbnails/afffa0bf1eed11920c56956b71ee5195/5b979e22 but I don't think that's the problem. It just fails on certain images, when updating the db record, but some of base64 data returning from the function looks off to my uneducated eye.

I would love help strengthening this function to avoid generating corrupt data and in general, better handle thousands of images that might be JPG, PNG, HEIF, BMP and just skip incompatible formats.

```
async getBase64FromUrl(url) {
  const data = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await data.blob();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result;
      resolve(base64data);
    };
  });
},
```

Example base64 output from one record below the function that *seems* corrupt to me, but maybe the endless AAAAAAAAAA's are whitespace?

````
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RDuRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7AAIAAAAMAAAISodpAAQAAAABAAAIVpydAAEAAAAYAAAQzuocAAcAAAgMAAAAPgAAAAAc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAENvbm9yIE1vcmFuAAAFkAMAAgAAABQAABCkkAQAAgAAABQAABC4kpEAAgAAAAM1NQAAkpIAAgAAAAM1NQAA6hwABwAACAwAAAiYAAAAABzqAAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMjAxOTowNDozMCAxNzoyOTo1OAAyMDE5OjA0OjMwIDE3OjI5OjU4AAAAQwBvAG4AbwByACAATQBvAHIAYQBuAAAA/+ELHmh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8APD94cGFja2V0IGJlZ2luPSfvu78nIGlkPSdXNU0wTXBDZWhpSHpyZVN6TlRjemtjOWQnPz4NCjx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iPjxyZGY6UkRGIHhtbG5zOnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyI+PHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9InV1aWQ6ZmFmNWJkZDUtYmEzZC0xMWRhLWFkMzEtZDMzZDc1MTgyZjFiIiB4bWxuczpkYz0iaHR0cDovL3B1cmwub3JnL2RjL2VsZW1lbnRzLzEuMS8iLz48cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0idXVpZDpmYWY1YmRkNS1iYTNkLTExZGEtYWQzMS1kMzNkNzUxODJmMWIiIHhtbG5zOnhtcD0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLyI+PHhtcDpDcmVhdGVEYXRlPjIwMTktMDQtMzBUMTc6Mjk6NTguNTUzPC94bXA6Q3JlYXRlRGF0ZT48L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj48cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0idXVpZDpmYWY1YmRkNS1iYTNkLTExZGEtYWQzMS1kMzNkNzUxODJmMWIiIHhtbG5zOmRjPSJodHRwOi8vcHVybC5vcmcvZGMvZWxlbWVudHMvMS4xLyI+PGRjOmNyZWF0b3I+PHJkZjpTZXEgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj48cmRmOmxpPkNvbm9yIE1vcmFuPC9yZGY6bGk+PC9yZGY6U2VxPg0KCQkJPC9kYzpjcmVhdG9yPjwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPjwvcmRmOlJERj48L3g6eG1wbWV0YT4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0ndyc/Pv/bAEMABgQFBgUEBgYFBgcHBggKEAoKCQkKFA4PDBAXFBgYFxQWFhodJR8aGyMcFhYgLCAjJicpKikZHy0wLSgwJSgpKP/bAEMBBwcHCggKEwoKEygaFhooKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKP/AABEIANIBGAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAdAAADAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAACAkHBgUBBAID/8QAVBAAAAUCAgMJCwcIBwgDAAAAAAECAwQFBgcREiE3CBMxQVF0dbKzFDU2YXFyc5GxwcIiMlKBkqHRFSMzNEJioqMWF0NTVYKUGCRWY4OEk9InKMP/xAAUAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFBEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AZkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcJjBfTdjWwqQySHKrKPeobStZGvjUfiLh9Q7SdLYgQn5cx1LUdhBuOOKPIkpIszMJbiFd7153VKrb2kmE3mzBZP9hsuPynwmA962cYLloFWbfqk56qsOKzkMPK1ZGevQ+iZcWWoNFaVy0y66O1UqNIJ5hepRHqU2rjSouIwhD7hrWZmfCPesO8qpZVbRUKU78k8kvMK+Y8nkMvYfEAfIA5qwrypV60VE+kulpFkT0dRlpsq5FF7D4x0oAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP8pUqPEZN2W+0w0R5Gt1ZJTn5TH4f6QUb/F6d/qUfiA9MA/lpxDraHGlpW2siUlSTzJRHwGR8ZD+gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGL1/dFWpRK5UKVKh1RUiFIcjOGhtJpNSFGk8vlcGZDVrarEe4bfp1XhpWmNOYQ+2lwslElRZln4xPXFPaZdnS0rtVB6sGtlFpdGsdQgHZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPzVOUUKnyZJ/2TZry5TItRAOFxJqseWR0ZSTdYzI5CSyyPj0Tz4eI8vvGH4gWI3JaOdbaCQaSzVELUlXLo8h+LgP29264t51bjijUtajUoz4zMCFmg9WsuTlALEvSSpSVpNKknkpJlkZHyD+DG1YgWQ1Wml1GlJS3USL5SeAnvEf73Ifr8WLPtuMPOMvtqbdbM0rQosjSZcRkA9qzrqqloVpqpUZ823U6loP5jqeNKi4yDnYa35TL7oiZcFaWpjZEUmIpWamle9PIYRJRj0rWuepWnXI9Vo75tSGT1pzPRcTxpUXGRgKFAHMYcXhDvi1ItZglvZrzbeZM8zacL5yT+4y8RkOnAAAAAAAAAYluvX95wmQj++qLKP4Vq+EJQHB3Z7+jYdEYz/SVLTy5dFpZfEE+AURwYkd04T2m5yU5lH2Ukn3Dsxmu5wkd0YLWyrPM0tutn/leWXuGlAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB5d1Vpq3LbqdZktOOswI65C228tJRJLMyLPVmA9QAw6090ZQrluWm0WNRamy9OfSwhxxTeik1HlmeR55DcQE5MU9pl2dLSu1UHpwa2UWl0ax1CHP1jAixqvVptSmwZSpUx5ch1SZKiI1qUajMi4tZjRKFSotDo0Kl09KkQ4bSWWkqVpGSUlkWZ8YD9wAAAAAAAAAAAA52/3t6tmQRHkbikI+/P3DohyOJijKhMEXAchPVUAy9xZkeRcI+oXnqPhH+Lh/LMx/DDzb7ZOMuIcQf7SDzL1gP2pM0qLL6yPjHLX/ZUe5I6pkLQZqaE6lnwLL6KvcfEOlaVmaSMfoSo0KzSYBWprD0OQ5HltLZfbVorQssjIx5j68zyDC4mWmzcNPOVGSlFTaT+bUXC4X0FeLkPiMLq6SkrUlZGSiPIyPhIwG57ku6VUy9pNBfcyi1VozbSZ6ieQRmXrTpF6g34m5blVfodep9ViGZPw30Po8ZpMjy+vgFHYUlqbDYlR1aTL7aXUK5UqLMj9RgP9gAAAAAAAWjdsP6NLtSP9N6Qv7KWy+IK45FNFNYlHwOuuNl/lJB/GGO3bD+lVbUj5/MZkLy8qkF8IxauwjZwztSXo5d0TJ5Z8ujvBfiAbbcpP79g3T0f3Ml9v+M1fENfGE7jmQTuF89rPWzVHSy8RtNH7zG7AAA+aSfpF6x9AAB80k/SL1j6AAAM8uEfNJP0i9YD6OOxl2UXb0Y/1DHYjjcZTL+qm7SzLP8mP9QwCRYK7WbT6RZ6woeJ4YK7WbT6Ra6woeRkfAZGAAD5pFyl6x9AAAD5pJ+kXrAfQAI8+AAAAPmkn6ResfcyLhMADj8Tu8sbnBdVQ7Acfid3ljc4LqqAYpekhUW2as6gzSsmFkRlxGZZe8YzZd1Sbcll852C4f51nP+JPIftGvYg+CFW9F7yC+gGYpFRi1aG1Lguk4w5rI+Ay8RlxH4h6iV8SuELjalyy7dmk4wZrjLMt+YM9Sy5S5D8Y3qh1eHW6eiZT3NNpWoyP5yD5FchgPWWnTQpJ8CiyC74sUf8AJt0LkIToszC30vEv9ovYf+YMMhWeo9fjGdY2Uvum3EzEJ+VFdSsz/dV8k/vNPqAYWkg+2BVT/KuE1tvqVpLbjdzqz/5ajR7EkEPisKfeShJcIcfctS0uWFMgpPMoc5SS8ikJP26QDZQAAAAAAAT7dnyNK/aLH/u6YS/tOuF8I5K8YWhufcPpWXzps/715f8A5j2N16/vuLCG8895pzKPJ8paviH78Q4KWtyvYDhJyNE1Z5+k39R+4B3e4rkGq1bjjZ6m5rbmXnIy+AMRJ1R3cvoH7AsG4lkfKu6OfGUVwv5pH7gz8n9Wd8w/YAm3BrtXOpRyOqTzI3U6u6F8vlFKBMWB3zj+mT1hToBNap12rlUZRFVZ5ETqtXdC+U/GKTMa2W/NL2CZFU75S/TL9pillQllAoUmYeWUeMp48/3UmfuAJlug8UqvXr2n0ul1CRFotOdOO22w4aN9Wk8lOKMuHXnlxZeUxlP5erH+Kz/9Qv8AEee84t55bjijU4tRqUZ8JmY/kAy25XxOqb1xFaddmuy40ptSoS3l6SmnElpGjM9eRpIzy4jLVwjwt13UJjOJrcZqU+iOumNaTSXDJCs1uZ5lnkYy3DCoKpeIttTEqNO9VFjSP901kSvuMxpG7A2rs9GM9dwBibLrjDqXWVqbcSeaVoPIyPlIwye44qM2bdNwJmTJMhKYaDSTrqlkR6fFmYWgMZuLPCu4uZI7QBmmL9aqjOKV1ts1Ka22ipPklKX1ERFpnqIsw7mFzi3cNbVcdWpbi6XGUpSjzMzNpOszCKYybV7t6Tf65h6MKdmNp9FReySAXXdTYm1P+k67Uoc16JChJSctTCzSp51RErRMy15JIy1cuefAQwL8vVj/ABWf/qF/iPQxGnqql/3HNWo1b9UH1EefFpnkXqyHOgNMwhxTrVn3ZEdl1GVIo77iW5jDzhrToGeRqLPgUnPMsuTLjD7JMlJJSTIyMsyMuMS9LUYo5hdUFVTDi2JrijU47TmDWZ8aiQRH95GAQ28q5VkXhXEIqc5KEz3yIikLIiLfFauEdBiziLWK/X248apSmadTmW4rLbTqkkakpIlrPLhM1EevkyHHXr4ZV7n8jtFDxjMzMzMzMz5QGz7nvFCrUG94FMqlQkSaNUnSjuNvuGsmlq1JWkz4NeRH4vIGsxO7yxucF1VCd7Dq2H23WlGlxCiUky4SMjzIxQa+ZRTrRpUsssn1Nu6v3mzP3gMWxC8D6t6P3kF8DBYheCFW9H7yC/EAB7Fs3BNt6oJkwl5oPInGj+a4nkP8R/Vq21UrpnSIdGZJ+W1HXJJrPI1pSZZknx6+DjHjuNqbWpDiTQ4gzSpJlkZGXCRkAZO2q5DuCA3LhLz4nGz+chXIY/u7YH5StyoxSLSU4wskF+9lq+/IYrhhVV0y7YiNIyZln3OtOeozV80/tZeswx1F3r8qxSfSSmzWWZHxgFShtlEi74ovziy1eIgxm4/lm5HumOZ56Dkdz1k4R9UgvNzJ7kq82KngYeW0Reaoy9w3DcbuGVTuhviUzHV6lL/EA0AAAAAAAAIpupHyexqrSC/sW47f8lCviGl4pQjTuTLS1foihvfaQr/3GP7oR85GMt0LM88pCW/stpT7gw+LkHQ3KkJoyzOLT6cefjI2kn7TAZ/uLZGjd9wx89TkFLmXmuEXxBtZP6s75h+wJnuO5G9YpS2j4HqY6n6ycbV7jDmSf1Z3zD9gCZMDvnH9MnrCnQmLA75x/TJ6wp0AmLVO+Uv0y/aYoxfR5Yd3CZcJUqQf8lQnPVO+Uv0y/aYovfezm4uiZPYqAT1tGmJrV10aluGaUTprMZRlwkS1knV6w6dYwGsFyizGolF3iQbCibeS+4akK0dStasj15cIT7CvadaPS8Ttkii8n9Wd8w/YAmfb6jRX6asuFMls/wCMg7uPVi27VrRuG4p9OS7WIdMc3iQa1EaNAlGnUR5ajM+IJBQ+/dP5w31iFBcZdlF29GP9QwCK4XUyJWcRLdptSaJ6HKmttPNmZlpJM9ZZlrD4Wbh7bNmypEi3KYmG9IQTbiicUrSSR55azPjCN4K7WbT6RZ6woeAnbjJtXu3pN/rmHowp2Y2n0VF7JIRfGTavdvSb/XMPRhTsxtPoqL2SQE8quvfKzNXxqfWfrUYfKlYN2HGpkRly24L7jbSUqddSZqWZFrMzz4TCFz++0j06usKbtfokeQgE8MY6FFtrE24KTTm96hx3yNpvPPQSpJLItfEWlkHTwEUasHrVM+HuQi9SlEFF3SO2y5vPZ7BsNzgFsdtbmvxqAIpevhnXukH+0UG+sPAuyXbIozlXpJyqhIhtvSHlPrIzWtJKPLIyIiLPIvIFBvXwyr3P5HaKFFrU8F6PzNnqEAnJddNTRrorFLQZqTCmPRiM+EyQs0+4PDUTzwrtMz4TixewCY4pbTbu6Xl9ssOXVM/6qbSyPL/dYvF/yAGWYh+CFW9F8RBfhv2ICiO0KsWZEre/iIYfRaRPrcpcalRnJMhDSnjabLNRpSWZ5Fx6uIBqu5U2p/8AYPe1A57dAtpbxhuQkJSlO+tnkRZazZQZn6zHQ7lQjLFQyMsjKA9mX+ZA8HdC7Y7k9I12LYDgqc8cefGeRqNt1KyPxkZGGtQre321lwkoj+8KY3qcSfjINg9+z5ACz4heG9aMs/lSlr+0efvGz7jjv3cvN2esoY3iSWV71Uv+Yk/4EjZNxx37uXm7PWUAaQAAAAAAAJ1YvP8AdOKd2OFwflSQn7Lhp9wcPGOF/wDXyrRUp/Q01jVyaBtn8ISy7Vqn35WVl8pUipPH5TU6f4h9cXIpPYUXUwRak0t8yIv3WzMvYAUjcqv7zjNTEZ5b8xIb8v5s1fCHjk/qzvmH7Ag+51kdzY0Wysv2nnG/tNLT7w/En9Wd8w/YAmTA75x/TJ6wp0JiwO+cf0yesKdAJi1TvlL9Mv2mKL33s5uLomT2KhOiqd8pfpl+0xRe+9nNxdEyexUAQfCvadaPS8TtkCjDqTWytJcKkmRCc+Fe060el4nbIFGwCdU3c03nGqUV9yZRTQ06hasn155EZH9AMnjLsou3ox/qGOyHHYy7KLt6Mf6hgEhwV2s2n0iz1hQ8TwwV2s2n0iz1hQ8BO3GTavdvSb/XMPRhTsxtPoqL2SQi+Mm1e7ek3+uYejCnZjafRUXskgJ4T++0j06usKbtfokeaQmRP77SPTq6wpu1+iR5pAEI3SO2y5vSM9g2G6wC2O2tzX41BRd0jtsub0jPYNhusAtjtrc1+NQBFL18Mq9z+R2ihRa1PBej8zZ6hCdN6+GVe5/I7RQotangvR+Zs9QgE98Utpt3dLy+2WHLqmyi0uaxewCaYpbTbu6Xl9ssOXVNlFpc1i9gAya/yL+idUzIj/N8ZeMhze5g2tQubvdUdJiB4J1X0fvIcFgZcUG18SKbUKqs2oZktlbmWpGknIjPxZ5AG4g4c0im4hquylp7lkPR3GZEdCSJtxSjSe+EXEeo8+XPy5qduhS/+Y7k9I12LYeRh5t9lDzC0uNLSSkrSeZKI+AyMYjj1g6V1E/cFupJNcSkjeYM/kyiIiIsuRZEWRcRgFGR84vKGwe/ZCpPMuxpC2JDa2nm1mlaFpyUkyPIyMg1r37PkALXiX4c1Xz0dRI2Pccd+7l5uz1lDHcS9V81Xz0dmkbFuOO/dy83Z6ygDSAAAAD4pRISaj1ERZj6PwXC/wBy0CpSC4Wozq/UgzATmt0jqF70wtZnJqLX8ThfiKHXwx3TZdfYyz32nyEZcubaiE/sLWCkYmWo0fAqqxiP/wAqRRSe13RBkMnwONqR6yyATzwdf7mxVtRwzyL8pMJM/OWSfeKHyf1Z3zD9gm3Zb5wr2oT5nkbNQYXnyaLiT9wpJJ/VnfMP2AJkwO+cf0yesKdCYsDvnH9MnrCnQCYtU75S/TL9pii997Obi6Jk9ioToqnfKX6ZftMUXvvZzcXRMnsVAEHwr2nWj0vE7ZAo2JyYV7TrR6XidsgUbAA47GXZRdvRj/UMdiOOxl2UXb0Y/wBQwCQ4K7WbT6RZ6woeJ4YK7WbT6RZ6woeAnbjJtXu3pN/rmHowp2Y2n0VF7JIRfGTavdvSb/XMPRhTsxtPoqL2SQE8J/faR6dXWFN2v0SPNITIn99pHp1dYU3a/RI80gCEbpHbZc3pGewbDdYBbHbW5r8agou6R22XN6RnsGw3WAWx21ua/GoAil6+GVe5/I7RQotangvR+Zs9QhOm9fDKvc/kdooUWtTwXo/M2eoQCe+KW027ul5fbLDl1XZRaXNYvYBNMUtpt3dLy+2WHLquyi0uaxewAZNf/gnVfR+8hgnEN7v7wTqvo/eQwTMAxm5SvWqPVl21Zbpv04oy5DGmeamVJNOZEf0T0j1coaAJruVNqn/YPe1A7quYuTbHxuuCn1JTsq33HWtJrPNUczZRmpHvLjAY7jaRJxbuUiLL/ez9hDeXuIL5i1UItVxKrk+nvJfiSJBONOJ4FJNKdYYN7iALXiX4c1Xz0dmkbFuOO/dy83Z6yhjuJfhzVfPR2aRsW447+XLzdnrKANIAAAAOaxNf7mw4ul7PLQpck8y9EodKOGxyf7nwiutZccFaPtZJ94CfMZ96LIbfjOuMvtqJSHG1GlSTLgMjLgMev/S65P8AiCr/AOtc/wDYeIPgD/aK8bMxl7M9JDhLz8h5inDqychLWXApszL1CYXGQpZQZHdVo06Rnnv0FtzPlzbIwE3IHfOP6ZPWFOhMWB3zj+mT1hToBMWqd8pfpl+0xRe+9nNxdEyexUJ0VTvlL9Mv2mKL33s5uLomT2KgCD4V7TrR6XidsgUbE5MK9p1o9LxO2QKN8QAHHYy7KLt6Mf6hjpSqtPMyIp8QzPkeT+I5rGXZRdvRj/UMAkOCu1m0+kWesKHieGCu1m0+kWesKHgJ24ybV7t6Tf65h6MKdmNp9FReySEXxk2r3b0m/wBcw9GFOzG0+iovZJATwn99pHp1dYU3a/RI80hMif32kenV1hTdr9EjzSAIRukdtlzekZ7BsN1gFsdtbmvxqCi7pHbZc3pGewbDdYBbHbW5r8agCKXr4ZV7n8jtFCi1qeC9H5mz1CE6b18Mq9z+R2ihRa1PBej8zZ6hAJ74pbTbu6Xl9ssOXVdk9pc1i9gE0xS2m3d0vL7ZYdGe3pYQW0r6ESIf8ki94DIL98E6r6I/aQwQgwN7Mm7a1WSnh3hSvUWfuC/ANi3Km1P/ALB72oHg7oTbFcfpGuxbH+GCN2RLMv8AiVKpkvuJba47qklmbZKy+Vlx5GRfUDHWZHqGK1dlwn234zxsrbcbVpJUk2G8jIwHBp1mXlDVb+XyEKPJWWReMKqn5xeUM9K4SAL7iWed81Uy+mjqJGx7jjv3cvNmesoYxiF4ZVPzk9RI2fcb9/Ll5uz1lAGlAAAAGYbpd/eMFLiPPI1kwgvrfbGnjHN1k/vWD0tH99LYR/FpfCAWbc/WvTbvxJi0utsHIgGw8442SjTnknVrLXwmQaj+oLDz/BV/6hz8RgG4+ZJzFZ9Z/wBlTHll9ttPvDpgJy4pUeNQMRLgpUBG9xIstbbKDMz0UZ5kWZ+Iw9uGkjurCq2XuNVIjkflJpJe4Jlujmd4xpuZGWWbrS/tMoV7w22Bb/dOCltrzzyhG39lSk+4AhMDvnH9MnrCnQmJBMiqUcz4CdT7RTvMss+IBMWqd8pfpl+0xRe+9nNxdEyexUJzT1k5OkLTwKcUZesUZvvZzcXRUnsVAEHwr2nWj0vE7ZAovJ/VnfMP2Cc+FhknE20jM8iKrxMz/wCskUXlGSYrxnwEgz+4BNChuL/LdP8AlK/WG+P94hQPGXZRdvRj/UMT6offun84b6xCguMuyi7ejH+oYBIcFdrNp9Is9YUPE78F1EjFi0zUeRflJkvWoiFEAE7cZNq929Jv9cw9GFOzG0+iovZJCL4ybV7t6Tf65h6MKdmNp9FReySAnhP77SPTq6wpu1+iR5pCZFQ1VWTnxPK6xim7OtpGX0SAIRukdtlzekZ7BsN1gFsdtbmvxqCi7pAyPGu5jI8/zjJfyGw3WAWx21ua/GoAil6+GVe5/I7RQotangvR+Zs9QhOm9fDKvc/kdooUWtTwXo/M2eoQCe+KW027ul5fbLDvoZ37BqkllrRTIiy+pCPcEgxS2m3d0vL7ZYfS1Y/deGNGj8O+0hhBeU2UgMbmsJksPMLLNLqDQefIZZBbZ8VyFNfivpNLrKzQoj8QZtRZHrLg1Dlb+sdqvxjmQEk3U0J+p4uQ/H4wGDj7nnrPMx/clh2LIWxIQpt1s9FSFFkZGP8AMB9T84vKGdlcQWJPziDOyf2QC84g+GNS85PUSNo3G/fu5ebs9ZQxfEHwyqfnp6iRtO4379XNzdnrKANIAAAAMH3ZD+94ZU5rPW7VG9XKRNOn+A3gLlu039G17cj/AN5Mcc+yjL4gHGbjBnSvquP5akU3Qz8rqD+EOAFS3FDGlVrqf4kMR0faUs/hDWgEZ3VTG84zVNf98xHc/lkn4Qx+5je7qwRorZ5fm1SGv5yz94wTdhMb1itGXllv1MZX5fluJ+EbNuQ5G/YSqbzz3ioPN+T5KFfEASyQg2ZTqDzJSFmn6yMbbJ3Sl2v0Fyn9yU5Dy2DYOUlKtMjNOWmRZ5Z8flGb4p0ddBxFuKnLQaSamumgsv2FK0kH9kyHNRWHJMlphlJqddWSEpLjMzyIgH+Z8IpJebSn7BrrSCzW5TH0kXjNpRCb8lo2ZDrRnmaFGk/qMU43pEiDvLpZtuN6Ci5SMsjATKp8x6nz402KrQkR3UvNqyzyUkyMj9ZDb6pumLqnUqTDTT6Ywt9pTW/ISvNOZZGoiM8sxjFw0x6i12oUuUk0vw5DkdZGXGlRl7h54D1LYaN+5qS0ks1OTGUEXlWRCguLLRvYX3a2kjMzpUnIv+koJFgXRl1zFm2oyUGpDUtMpzkJLX5w8/s5fWH9rEJFTpM2A7qblMLYV5FJNJ+0BM6nzH6dPjzYbhtSY7iXWnC4UrSeZH9RkG33M2Jd0XzX6xFuWc3JZjRUuNklhDeSjXkZ/JIs9QUmow3qfUJMOUg0Px3VNOJP9lSTMjL1kGD3FnhXcXMkdoAyXGTavdvSb/XMPRhTsxtPoqL2SQi+Mm1e7ek3+uYejCnZjafRUXskgJ63C0bFfqTSiMjRJcSZHxZKMb/S91HVItNix5VvRX32m0oW6T6k6ZkWWlllqzGT410ZyhYqXLEWg0pVMXIb1cKHD3xOX1KHEAPZvCvybpuepVuclCJE143VJR81PIReIiIi+oPhgU0bOENqpPjhJX9ozP3ifTDS33m2mkGtxaiSlJFmZmeoiIUrtKl/kS1aPStWcKGzHPLlQgkn7AE6r18Mq9z+R2ihRa1PBej8zZ6hCdN6+GVe5/I7RQotangvR+Zs9QgE98Utpt3dLy+2WH+sDwEtzo2N2SQgOKW027ul5fbLD/WB4CW50bG7JIDLrmidw3DOYyySTpqSX7p6y+4x/kjWkh2GKVNMnI1SbL5Ki3lzLl4Un7fUOEYd0NSvmgObv+y2LjjnIjElqqIL5K+AnP3VfiMDmxX4Up2PLaW0+2eipCiyMjDWZkZZ8JDkr5s6NcsU3EaLNSQXyHstSv3VeLx8QBe0fPSXjDOST+b9YXR2kTIlcbpstlTUo3Ut6JlwmZkRZcoYuTq0QC9YheGVS89PUSNy3GjWcm63stZIjII/Kbh+4hhmIHhjUvOT1Ehj9x7TzZtOuTzLLuiYloj5SQjP4zAb+AAAAMmx7wuqGJjdERAqMaEmAbyl78hStM16GWWXJon6xrIAGS4B4VzMM0Vvu+oR5q6gbOibKDTokjT4c/PGtAAAxHHXBmfiPckCpwKnFhpjxCjKS82pRqMlqVnq84dPgXh/Nw5tebSZ85iYb8w5KVMpNJJzQhOR5+YNHAAxrG7BKPiFUGKtTZqKfV0oJp1S0aTbyC4DPLWSi4M+TyEOWw13ODlu3dBq9fq0eaxCWT7Udhsy0nEnmk1GfER68uPIgxwACmy9y3W35TzpXDTiJxZqIjZXqzPMNg2nQbSnkIiH9AAYZjJgIze9eOt0WoN06e8RFKQ62am3TIsiWWWslZERHy5evO/9lauf8RU7/wAKw24AGT4I4OxMOCkzZUsp9ZkJ3o3ko0UNN556KSPXryLMz5C+vWAAAYHi7ufWrwuR2t0GotU6TKPSlNOtmpC1/TTlrIz4/Hr4x6mA+D9Qw2rFTmT6nFmolsJZSllCkmkyVnmeY2gABZL53OFYuO8a1WWK5BZany3JCW1tLM0kpRnkeQYSzqS5QbTo1IecS67BhtRlOJLIlGhBJMy9Q9cADI8b8GouIzsaoQ5aafWWEb0bqkaSHW88yJRFrzLM8j8eXJlkn+ytXP8AiKnf+FYbcABesLNzo3bFzR6zcVTZqBw1k7HjstmlG+FwKUZ8OXCRcvqDCgAAVavbmStVKu1Ge3X6ehEqS4+lJtLzSSlGrI/WGeo8RUCkQYa1EpUdhDRqLgM0pIs/uH6wAFeu/c11muXZWqszXoDTU+a9KS2ppZmkluGoiPxlmGQtunrpNu0unOLS4uHFajqWksiUaEEkzL1D0QAPy1SCzUoD0SQWbbqcj5SPiMhilbpcikT1xZScjLWhXEsuIyG6jza9R4tahKjyk6+FDhcKD5SAYi28bZa9aR+pCiUkjSeZGPlxUiVRZK48pOrhQ4XAss+Eh5cWQbKsj1o5AHprp0GW+3Jkw2HZLGtl1ac1N+Qx+GfqX9Q9aGtLiFKSeZGQ8WoOEbjqiPURGAXq9vzt31I08bhF/CRB1cEbeXbOGlGhPpNElxs5LxGWslOHpZH4yIyL6guuDFlneuJ86ozGjXSKfIU86Z8C1aR6CPHnlmfiI+UOIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8+uUiLWYC4sxBGRl8lZfOQfKQxO5aDLoE448ktJpWtt0vmrL8fEN8H46vTItWgrizWyW2rgPjSfKR8RgF8bdW2kyQoyI+HIx/hMS+6wbMNs3ZTxk202X7SzPIi9Y6O5LVn0WWaN6U/HUZm262kzzLx8hjrsNbYcjulVqi0aFkWUZtZZGnPhWZfcX1gPdw2tGNZdqRKUxkt8i3yS8Ra3XT+crycReIiHUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//ZDQo=```
````

Comment: Whether it looks wrong to you or not, what you have there is a valid 280x210 JPEG image.  What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: When you declare a function `async`, it automatically returns a promise. There's no need to end with `return new Promise...`

Comment: Long sections of the string that is the same letter repeated, where most are largely random throughout. Maybe that's whitespace? In any case, and regardless, Airtable is rejecting some of them and it's not easy to debug their error which is `error: "INVALID_VALUE_FOR_COLUMN"
message: "Field \"LogoBase64\" cannot accept the provided value"` -- why not if it's a valid string which is the field type.

Comment: Images aren't text, they don't have "whitespace". But they do often have large areas with the same color.

Comment: That error may mean that the value is too long for the field.

Comment: The 'long text' data type in Airtable is a string up to 100,000 characters. Most of these images are around 25,000 but I checked and some are as much as 300,000 so that's probably it. Ugh.